# Modifying excel cell values based on their length with a UDF

Tags: vba

I was asked to modify some phone number values in an excel column and I wanted to use the opportunity to make a UDF for the first time.

Currently I have a list of phone numbers that vary in size. Some numbers are complete and some are incomplete (I.E. lengths range from 7 digits to 11). The target length for every number is 10 digits. If the number is greater than 10 digits I trim off the first number, if it is less i would append "0" to the beginning of the string until it was 10 digits long.

Im not entirely sure what I am doing wrong so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. At the moment I am getting a "#VALUE" in my function cell. I am targeting a cell that is formatted as a "text" cell. Any advice is appreciated! Here is my function...

```
Public Function phone_number_trim(phone_number As String)

Dim phone_number_length As Integer
Dim s_phone_number As String


phone_number_length = phone_number.Len
s_phone_number = phone_number

If phone_number_length > 10 Then s_phone_number = Mid(s_phone_number, 2, 10)

If phone_number_length < 10 Then
    For i = 0 To phone_number_length
    s_phone_number = "0" + s_phone_number
    Next
End If

phone_number = s_phone_number

End Function
```

Here is what my editor looks like just in case...
[Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mki6z.png)

Comment: If you call your function from a VBA sub you will get more information on what the problem might be.

Comment: ... and your error is at least here `phone_number_length = phone_number.Len` should be phone_number_length = Len(phone_number)`

Comment: `phone_number_trim = Right(String(10, "0") & Right(phone_number, 10), 10)`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is interested here is the function I ended up going with...

I ended up having to clean my data a bit so I wrote a supporting function. Its not perfect and I know there are cases where it would not work but i'll cross those bridges as they come!

```
Public Function prepare_the_subject(subject As String) As String

Dim bad_guys() As Variant
bad_guys = Array(" ", "-", ")", "(", "'", ".", "/", "\")
Dim test As String

test = subject

For Each guy In bad_guys
    test = Replace(test, guy, "")
Next guy

prepare_the_subject = test

End Function

Public Function phone_number_trim(phone_number As String) As String

Dim phone_number_length As Integer
Dim s_phone_number As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim zero_len As Integer

s_phone_number = phone_number
s_phone_number = prepare_the_subject(s_phone_number)
phone_number_length = Len(s_phone_number)
zero_len = 10 - phone_number_length

If phone_number_length > 10 Then s_phone_number = Mid(s_phone_number, 2, 10)

If phone_number_length < 10 Then
    For i = 1 To zero_len
    s_phone_number = "0" + s_phone_number
    Next
End If

phone_number_trim = s_phone_number

End Function
```